# Another question about CMOS tri-state buffer internal structure

Tags: digital-logic

About my previous question: [CMOS tri-state buffer internal structure](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224657/cmos-tri-state-buffer-internal-structure?noredirect=1#comment484527_224657)

I have just one more question: 
is the value that "activates" the transistor related to the value of the Output? Because if I choose the input "high" and the control "high" I will activate the top transistor in "low" but the output value should b e "high". So it's not related, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make this a self-contained question, including the circuit diagram?

Comment: You need to study how PMOS transistors work. Common source configuration is inverting for either PMOS or NMOS.

Comment: *is the value that "activates" the transistor related to the value of the Output?* **NO**, it is not, the transistors are either in a conductive state or not, depending on the gate-source voltage. Given enough gate-source voltage a conductive channel is formed between drain and source. This channel is formed regardless of the drain (output) voltage.

Comment: Thinking of transistors as "activated" is a shortcut that will mislead you until you learn how they actually work. There is no royal road to learning, as the saying goes.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly, the action of a MOSFET is controlled by the voltage between the gate and the source terminal. More detailed schematic symbols for MOSFETs make these two terminals look different:

[image]

In your circuit, the source is the one connected to the positive power supply node. The action is controlled by how far below the source is the gate voltage.